# How to inspect an element when right click opens up menu on the site

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to inspect an element in a website, but when I perform a right click the menu opens up. I dont see an option to Inspect. How can I inspect an element here.
Thank you for the help.

[image: right click opens menu options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Chrome DevTools
   Command+Option+C (Mac) or Control+Shift+C (Windows, Linux, ChromeOS).
2. Open the Command Menu
   Press Control+Shift+P or Command+Shift+P (Mac).
3. Start typing javascript, select Disable JavaScript. JavaScript is now disabled.
   Now when I right click on the element, I no longer see the Menu option. I can now inspect the element.

To re-enable JavaScript:

Open the Command Menu again and run the Enable JavaScript command.
Close DevTools.

Referenced [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/disable/#:%7E:text=Press%20Control%2BShift%2BP%20or,to%20open%20the%20Command%20Menu.&text=Start%20typing%20javascript%20%2C%20select%20Disable,JavaScript%20is%20now%20disabled.&text=The%20yellow%20warning%20icon%20next,you%20that%20JavaScript%20is%20disabled.)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to disable Javascript using one of many available plugins.

Another is to simply open developer tools and navigate to that element. There are few ways to do it:

- press <kbd>F12</kbd> (Works for Windows, Mac, Linux)
- Menu → Tools → Developer tools
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (works same way <kbd>F12</kbd>)
- If on MacOS, press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

*I used this [answer for reference](https://superuser.com/questions/552932/how-do-i-open-the-inspect-element-panel-when-right-click-context-menu-is-disab), but improved.*

Comment: Thanks @angelo-martins. Your answer let me know I will need to disable JavaScript in order for me to be able to inspect the element. I have shared how I achieved this in my comment below. Thanks again for your response.